# how to avoid ConcurrentHashMap usage

Tags: java, hadoop

I have written this code inside the run() method of the Reducer class in Hadoop

```
@Override
    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        setup(context);

        ConcurrentHashMap<String, HashSet<Text>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, HashSet<Text>>();

        while (context.nextKey()) {
            String line = context.getCurrentKey().toString();
            HashSet<Text> values = new HashSet<Text>();
            for (Text t : context.getValues()) {
                values.add(new Text(t));
            }

            map.put(line, new HashSet<Text>());
            for (Text t : values) {
                map.get(line).add(new Text(t));
            }
        }

        ConcurrentHashMap<String, HashSet<Text>> newMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, HashSet<Text>>();

        for (String keyToMerge : map.keySet()) {
            String[] keyToMergeTokens = keyToMerge.split(",");
            for (String key : map.keySet()) {
                String[] keyTokens = key.split(",");
                if (keyToMergeTokens[keyToMergeTokens.length - 1].equals(keyTokens[0])) {
                    String newKey = keyToMerge;
                    for (int i = 1; i < keyTokens.length; i++) {
                        newKey += "," + keyTokens[i];
                    }
                    if (!newMap.contains(newKey)) {
                        newMap.put(newKey, new HashSet<Text>());
                        for (Text t : map.get(keyToMerge)) {
                            newMap.get(newKey).add(new Text(t));
                        }
                    }
                    for (Text t : map.get(key)) {
                        newMap.get(newKey).add(new Text(t));
                    }
                }
            }


        //call the reducers
        for (String key : newMap.keySet()) {
            reduce(new Text(key), newMap.get(key), context);
        }

        cleanup(context);
    }
```

my problem is that even if my input is too small it takes 30 minutes to run epsecially because of the **newMap.put()** call. If I put this command in comments then it runs quickly without any problems.
As you can see I use ConcurrentHashMap. I didn't want to use it because I think that run() is called only once at each machine (it doesn't run concurrently) so I would not have any problem with a simple HashMap but if I replace the concurrentHashMap with the simple HashMap I am getting an error (concurrentModificationError). 
Does anyone have an idea about how to make it work without any delays ?
thanks in advance!

*java6
*hadoop 1.2.1

Comment: Could this be a candidate for CodeReview?

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you explain?

Comment: @developer If you have **working** code that you would like to improve, [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is a good place to put it.

Comment: ok! thank you ;) 
I didn't know it!

Comment: where specifically is the concurrent modification exception thrown? It is almost certainly cause by mutating the map while iterating over the keyset, entryset, or values.

Comment: With java6 String.split() method is a performance killer, use org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.splitPreserveAllTokens(String str,char separatorChar) instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it would solve your performance problems, but I see one inefficient thing you are doing :

```
newMap.put(newKey, new HashSet<Text>());
for (Text t : map.get(keyToMerge)) {
    newMap.get(newKey).add(new Text(t));
}
```

It would be more efficient to keep the HashSet in a variable instead of searching for it in newMap :

```
HashSet<Text> newSet = new HashSet<Text>();
newMap.put(newKey, newSet);
for (Text t : map.get(keyToMerge)) {
    newSet.add(new Text(t));
}
```

Another inefficient thing you are doing is create a HashSet of values and then create another identical HashSet to put in the map. Since the original HashSet (`values`) is never used again, you are constructing all those Text objects for no reason at all.

Instead of:

```
    while (context.nextKey()) {
        String line = context.getCurrentKey().toString();
        HashSet<Text> values = new HashSet<Text>();
        for (Text t : context.getValues()) {
            values.add(new Text(t));
        }

        map.put(line, new HashSet<Text>());
        for (Text t : values) {
            map.get(line).add(new Text(t));
        }
    }
```

You can simply write :

```
    while (context.nextKey()) {
        String line = context.getCurrentKey().toString();
        HashSet<Text> values = new HashSet<Text>();
        for (Text t : context.getValues()) {
            values.add(new Text(t));
        }

        map.put(line, values);
    }
```

EDIT :

I just saw the additional code you posted as an answer (from your `cleanup()` method) :

```
    //clear map
    for (String s : map.keySet()) {
        map.remove(s);
    }
    map = null;

    //clear newMap
    for (String s : newMap.keySet()) {
        newMap.remove(s);
    }
    newMap = null;
```

The reason this code gives you `ConcurrentModificationError` is that foreach loops don't support modification of the collection you are iterating over.

To overcome this, you can use an Iterator :

```
    //clear map
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, HashSet<Text>>> iter1 = map.entrySet ().iterator ();
    while (iter1.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, HashSet<Text>> entry = iter1.next();
        iter1.remove();
    }
    map = null;

    //clear newMap
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, HashSet<Text>>> iter2 = newMap.entrySet ().iterator ();
    while (iter2.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, HashSet<Text>> entry = iter2.next();
        iter2.remove();
    }
    newMap = null;
```

That said, you don't really have to remove each item separately.
You can simply write

```
map = null;
newMap = null;
```

When you remove the reference to the maps, the garbage collector can garbage collect them. Removing the items from the maps makes no difference.

Comment: I thought that I had it in O(1) time.
thanks anyway but this is nothing in front of the main problem :(